# creating new triple using sparql query

Tags: eclipse, sparql, jena

I've tried to execute this following java code to create new triples using the SPARQL CONSTRUCT feature.

```
package jenasemweb;


 import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
 import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.PrintUtil;

    public class SparqlQuery03 {
 public static void main(String [] args) {

 // LOAD Raw Model from URL
 Model myRawModel =
 FileManager.get().loadModel(
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/Houghland.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/cruz.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/abraham.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/akundi.v2.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
"http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/bennett.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/hanna.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/liew_hw2.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/ramani.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/rawal.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/sison.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/tara.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/turney.n3", "N3");

 // READ another N3 into the Model
 FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/wilson.n3", "N3");

 // Create an RDFS inference model from the Raw Model
 InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createRDFSModel(myRawModel);

 // Create a new SPARQL query
 String queryString =
 "PREFIX drc: <http://www.codesupreme.com/onto/cse7392/#> " +
 "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
 "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> " +
 "SELECT DISTINCT ?lname ?fname " + // space after last ?var
 "WHERE {" +
 " ?who foaf:lastName ?lname." +
 " ?who foaf:firstName ?fname." +
 " }" +
 "ORDER BY ?lname";

 // create a Jena query from the queryString
 com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

 // create a Jena QueryExecution object that knows the query
 // and the N3 over which the query will be run
 QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, infmodel);


 // execute the query - get back a ResultSet
 ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

 // iterate over the result set
 while(results.hasNext()) {
 QuerySolution sol = results.next();
 System.out.println("Solution:" + sol.toString() );
 }}}
```

but the execution return the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 119, col: 27] Unrecognized: [DOT]
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:163)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.exceptionDirect(LangEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.exception(LangEngine.java:149)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesNodeCompound(LangTurtleBase.java:408)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesNode(LangTurtleBase.java:388)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.objectList(LangTurtleBase.java:350)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectItem(LangTurtleBase.java:288)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectList(LangTurtleBase.java:269)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:250)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:44)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:687)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:208)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:141)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.AdapterFileManager.readModelWorker(AdapterFileManager.java:291)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.readModel(FileManager.java:369)
    at jenasemweb.SparqlQuery03.main(SparqlQuery03.java:44)
```

I am new to this,extremely new. So all help is appreciated.

Comment: As @jkbkot points out the error relates to a problem parsing one of your data files, without posting a snippet of the relevant file around the position given in your error (`[line: 119, col: 27]`) people can't help you any further

Comment: A note about your data:  I see in http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/rawal.n3 many triples of the form `foaf:person a rdfs:class.`  Those should probably use [`rdfs:Class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_class) instead (note the capital `C`).

Comment: sorry guys, I made a mistake when copy-pasting the provided code, the file it complains about is http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/hanna.n3

Comment: I tried to run the file, and I'm getting an exception on line 36 (not 44), i.e. http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/akundi.v2.n3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to your SPARQL query. It is about a problem parsing the file `http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/hanna.n3` (at least that's on line `44` in the snippet you provided).
I tried to run the file, and I'm getting an exception on line 36 (not 44), i.e. http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/akundi.v2.n3

It could maybe be a problem with a URI ending with a dot, probably in the object of the triple. Is it possible that you're using Jena 2.11.0 or older?

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-584 --> you could try to upgrade to Jena 2.11.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but I'm using the last version of jena.

Comment: @user3347859 so it might be a syntax problem in the file or another bug. It would be useful to see what's on line 119 in that file.

Comment: @user3347859 This is going to be hard to diagnose, since we've got no copy of the file here that we can depend on staying the same.  I just pulled down http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/rawal.n3 and Jena's `rdfcat` reads it without an issue.  Have you changed it without telling us? :)

Comment: No, I haven't changed it

Comment: when I've delated the the following lines:  FileManager.get().readModel(myRawModel,
 "http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392.semweb/onto/a3/akundi.v2.n3", "N3"); no errors are returened  thanks jkbkot

Comment: JENA-584 was about the writer getting it wrong.  Dots can not end a localname, they have to be internal.  Stylistically, adding a space before the triple-ending DOT is normal.

Comment: By the way, it's better to use ".ttl" and a language of "TTL" than ".n3"/"N3".